# XQuery difference between "where" on a "for" clause and "where" on a "let" clause

Tags: xml, xquery

Consider the following XML:

```
<bib>
<book year="1994">
    <title>TCP/IP Illustrated</title>
    <author><last>Stevens</last><first>W.</first></author>
<publisher>Addison-Wesley</publisher>
<price>65.95</price>
</book>

<book year="2000">
    <title>Data on the Web</title>
    <author><last>Abiteboul</last><first>Serge</first></author>
    <author><last>Buneman</last><first>Peter</first></author>
    <author><last>Suciu</last><first>Dan</first></author>
    <publisher>Morgan Kaufmann Publishers</publisher>
    <price>39.95</price>
</book>

<book year="1999">
    <title>The Economics of Technology and Content for Digital TV</title>
    <editor><last>Gerbarg</last><first>Darcy</first><affiliation>CITI</affiliation></editor>        
    <publisher>Kluwer Academic Publishers</publisher>
    <price>129.95</price>
</book>
</bib>
```

I know that the following XQuery query

```
for $book in doc(“books.xml”)//book
where $book/price>60
return <expensiveBook>
{ $book/title/text() }
</expensiveBook>
```

will return exactly the title of the two books with the price greater then 60:

```
<expensiveBook>TCP/IP Illustrated</expensiveBook>
<expensiveBook>The Economics of Technology and Content for Digital TV</expensiveBook>
```

Instead the following query:

```
let $books := doc(“books.xml”)//book
where $books/price > 60 (: existential... :)
return <expensiveBooks>
{ $books/title }
</expensiveBooks>
```

Will return the whole of the three books in the XML doc:

```
<expensiveBooks>
    <title>TCP/IP Illustrated</title>
    <title>Data on the Web</title>
    <title>The Economics of Technology and Content for Digital TV</title>
</expensiveBooks>
```

I can't understand why it happens, shouldn't I have the whole of the books into the variable declared with "let" and then filter it with the where clause? Why it returns also the "Data on the Web" book which price is less than 60?

Another curious thing I can't understand is that a query like the following one:

```
let $books in doc(“books.xml”)//book[price>60]
return <expensiveBook>
{ $books/title }
</expensiveBook>
```

correctly returns only the two books with the price greater than 60:

```
<expensiveBooks>
    <title>TCP/IP Illustrated</title>
    <title>The Economics of Technology and Content for Digital TV</title>
</expensiveBooks>
```

How things work here? Why the behaviour isn't the one I expected? Does the where clause work differently on let and for clauses? And what about the last query, where a "let" clause is used but specifing the price element through the XPath syntax [element=value]?

Thanks for help, as always :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to find some basic resources on XPath and XQuery.
When you say:

```
let $books := doc(“books.xml”)//book
where $books/price > 60 (: existential... :)
return <expensiveBooks>
{ $books/title }
</expensiveBooks>
```

what that means is: bind $books to the sequence of all book elements, now consider the sequence of all price elements of books in the sequence: if any of them is more than 60, then return the sequence of all title elements of any of the book elements in $books, wrapped up in an element. So you get all or none.

Your first query said: iterate through this sequence of book elements, and if the one I have right now has a price more than 60, return the title.

The query with the constraint on the XPath:

```
let $books in doc(“books.xml”)//book[price>60]
return <expensiveBook>
{ $books/title }
</expensiveBook>
```

Says: construct a sequence of all the book elements whose price child element is more than 60, and return an element consisting of the sequence of all the titles of those books, wrapped in an element.

Let binds a variable; for binds a variable to each member of a sequence in turn. Path expressions over sequences produce other sequences. '=' and '>' are existential operators that operate over sequences and return a single boolean result.

Comment: With "now consider the sequence of all price elements of books in the sequence: if any of them is more than 60" you mean that it's enough that one of them is more than 60 or that every element must be more than 60?

Comment: what does "bind $books to the sequence of book elements" mean, though?  Certainly, there's a sequence of book elements.  Bind here is something like an iterator?

Answer (score 2):

The logic of a FLWOR expression is that it represents a stream of tuples, where the tuples are (variable-name, value) pairs. A let clause creates a single tuple: one variable, one value. A for clause creates a stream of tuples, one tuple for each item in the selection. A where clause filters the stream of tuples so only those tuples that satisfy the condition are retained.

If there is only one tuple to start with, the result of filtering using "where" can only be one tuple or no tuples.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you haven't applied a constraint to the sequence `$books`. This is essentially how that logic is evaluated: `Where any book has a price greater than 60, return all books`. As you've already discovered, you need to either constrain the sequence using an XPath predicate or constrain using `where` in an XQuery `for` iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you meant to to use "for" instead of "let"?

With "let" the output is, as you described:

output:

```
<expensiveBooks>
  <title>TCP/IP Illustrated</title>
  <title>Data on the Web</title>
  <title>The Economics of Technology and Content for Digital TV</title>
</expensiveBooks>
```

by changing to a "for" loop, the, I think, correct result is achieved.  How and why I'll leave to those who better understand xquery, but perhaps noting this distinction will be helpful to yourself or others.

My take is that without a "for" loop the "where" is never invoked.

output:

```
<expensiveBooks>
  <title>TCP/IP Illustrated</title>
</expensiveBooks>
<expensiveBooks>
  <title>The Economics of Technology and Content for Digital TV</title>
</expensiveBooks>
```

probably you were thinking of using "for"?

query:

```
xquery version "3.1";

for $books in db:open("bib")//book
where $books/price > 60
return <expensiveBooks>
{ $books/title }
</expensiveBooks>
```

I added your xml into a "bib" database for reference, else it's the same as referencing a document directly.

Interesting.